# failed to open stream: HTTP request failed

Tags: php, mysql, curl

i have a problem with a URL
it was working fine before 2-3hours now stopped working
when i use that on another server it seems working again 
in this stopped working 
i tried curl
no chance failed
let me know there is any other way to get that

this is error

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://#.#.#/?id=100) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in
```

Comment: did you check using your browser to see if the server is even working in the first place?

Comment: i don't think that's a valid url.

Comment: another thing i can got homw path of url seems it is working when i go to 404 url in that site it is also working when i go some directory it is not working thats make me crazy

Comment: when i open in browser it is working

Comment: Doesn't look like a PHP issue.

Comment: Could be anything.  You've got to get more information.  Use curl with the -v switch. Use the -o switch to dump the actual file data to /dev/null you are only interested in the session headers. Bang in multiple times if you need to.

Comment: @starbolin i don't understand do you have an link

Comment: @saleeh93 [here](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether they are blocking your IP address.

Answer (score 2):

It could be that you need to set headers, some sites don't allow you to view them without, try this:

```
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n" .
              "User-Agent:Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)\r\n"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$html = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

Comment: any way thanks for your replay it is also not working i understand why that come,the problem is they are blocking ip when more request comes :P